# How to expand both width and height on collapsible divs when clicked on?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a div which once when clicked on expands not only height wise (as it does now) but also width wise.

For example, if I have multiple rows, each row with 3 collapsed divs, once I click on any, it expands to the width of the whole row (so equal to 3 collapsed divs), and height depending on the amount of collapsed data (imagine it is an article and collapsed div is an article thumbnail, and when clicked on it expands and show the whole article/text).

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("aktualno");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}

filterSelection("all")

function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}
```

```css
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: white;
}

.filterDiv {
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="filterDiv Pilar1">
  <div class="articleBox">
    <button class="collapsible">A</button>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="filterDiv Pilar2 Pilar4">
  <div class="articleBox">
    <button class="collapsible">B</button>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="filterDiv Pilar1">
  <div class="articleBox">
    <button class="collapsible">C</button>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm stuck, pls help

Comment: Maybe when one is clicked, you can set the width of the other two boxes to 0% and set the width of the chosen box to 100%.

Comment: Do you have to use this explicit mockup? Or a you free to use another combination of HTML/CSS/JS? I would do it much, much, much more simple! If you you want me to show you feel free to leave a comment. Otherwise (if you have to or want to keep the same exact mockup) it would be a waste of time for me to show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are looking for correctly you could change a little of your JavaScript to get the width to update:

```
    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("aktualno");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;

    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
      content.parentElement.parentElement.style.width = "100px";
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      content.parentElement.parentElement.style.width = "100%";
    } 
  });
}
```

What this is doing is selecting the div containing the content eg: `<div class="filterDiv Pilar1">`  and setting the width to 100% if it is expanding and setting it to 100px if it is shrinking.

Comment: Yes! That’s it! Thank you sooooo much I spent two hours fiddling with CSS thinking the solution is there... I guess it’s time to start learning JS properly. Thanks again, i reckon this was a very basic question.